# Clear old text and input new text in Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nonetype

I am using Selenium to clear old text in a text area before input new text in a web browser. This is my code:

```
MY_UDP_SESSION = 32768
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("udp-session-quota").clear()
time.sleep(1)
elem.send_keys(MY_UDP_SESSION)
```

but I see this error:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'send\_keys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217451/selenium-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send-keys)

Answer (score 0):

### clear()

[`clear()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.clear) clears the text if it's a text entry element and is defined as:

```
def clear(self):
    """Clears the text if it's a text entry element."""
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
```

As `clear()` doesn't returns anything hence as per your line of code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("udp-session-quota").clear()
```

*elem* is assigned as **null** i.e. *NoneType*. Moving forward when you try to invoke `send_keys()` on **elem**:

```
elem.send_keys(MY_UDP_SESSION)
```

You see the error.

---

### Solution

Once the WebElement is returned then you can invoke `clear()` and `send_keys()` as follows:

```
MY_UDP_SESSION = "32768"
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("udp-session-quota")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(MY_UDP_SESSION)
```