# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How do I send my string, `imei` it's currently attached into a string which is visible in my code.

For finding the xpath function I attached it into a variable assuming that it would allow the `send_keys` property but it didn't.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

imei = 'id'
xpath = 'xpath here'
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('w3c', True)                 
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.t-mobile.com/resources/bring-your-own-phone")

time.sleep(2)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
elem.send_keys(imei)
```

XPath is also in a string because it's extremely lengthy and would make it very difficult to view. Nonetheless, it works still. The service goes to the webpage and clicks the path but it does not enter the value I want to input which is `imei`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'send\_keys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217451/selenium-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

This is the problem.  You're assigning elem to the result of the `click()` function, which doesn't return anything, therefore it returns `None`.

Assign elem to the element, then call `click()` separately as follows:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
elem.click()
elem.send_keys(...)
```

Comment: I tried this then received a few more errors after but thanks anyways. This should've worked, I believe the way you're finding xpath is now deprecated. I found a workaround though thanks anyways!